# Fetching JSON data with .netcore from a web api

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I made an api which have some data for example `www.example.com/data/select?indent=on&q=title:asthma`
gives the data in JSON format like

```
{
"responseHeader":{
"status":0,
"QTime":2,
"params":
{
"q":"title:asthma",
"indent":"on",
"wt":"json"
},
"response":{"numFound":1,"start":0, docs:[
{
"tstamp": "xxxx"
"id": "xxxxx"
"title": "Asthma is a medical term"
"url": "www.example.com/xxxx"
"content":"xxxxx"
}]}
}}
```

I want to call the same url from my .netcore application such that I can have title and url from the response and show it to my .netcore application. 
As a new to .netcore it is pretty tricky to get used to MVC architecture. My model look like this

```
namespace searchEngineTesting.Models
{
    public class SearchModel
    {
        public string Title {get; set;}
        public string Source {get; set;}

    }
}
```

How can I use controller that whenever triggers take a string as an input for example `cancer` and put it to the title of the api like `www.example.com/data/select?indent=on&q=title:cancer` and fetch the `title` and `url` from the response.

Comment: When you call `www.example.com/data/select?indent=on&q=title:asthma`,you could return  json string successfully,right?Do you mean that you want to call this api and get the response in core project.Then in this project you could fetch data(url and title) to deserialize to SearchModel?

Comment: @Rena yes, I want to call this api with my .netcore application and fetch out the response like only title and source..

Comment: Hi @Khan,did you try my code below?It works well on my project.

Comment: And by the way,in your json string,I could see `response` with url and title.What do you mean `source`?Does it mean the `url`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could fetch json data like below:

```
[HttpGet]
public  async Task<JsonResult> Get()
{
    var model = new SearchModel();
    var url = "https://localhost:5001/api/values/test";//it should be the url of your api
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        using (var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url))
        {
            using (var content = response.Content)
            {  
               //get the json result from your api
                var result = await content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var root = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);
                var items = root.SelectToken("responseHeader").Children().OfType<JProperty>().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value);
                foreach(var item in items)
                {
                    if(item.Key== "response")
                    {
                        var key = item.Value.SelectToken("").OfType<JProperty>().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value);

                        foreach (var k in key)
                        { 
                            if(k.Key== "docs")
                            {
                                var tests = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(k.Value.ToString());
                                var data = k.Value.SelectToken("").Children().First();
                                var test = data.SelectToken("").Children().OfType<JProperty>().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value);
                                foreach (var t in test)
                                {
                                    if (t.Key == "url")
                                    {
                                        model.Source = t.Value.ToString();
                                    }
                                    else if (t.Key=="title")
                                    {
                                        model.Title = t.Value.ToString();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                return new JsonResult(model);
            }
        }
    }
}
[HttpGet("[Action]")]
public string test() 
{
   //for easy testing,I just read your json file and return string
    var jsonstring = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("C:\\test.json");
    return jsonstring;
}
```

Comment: it still gives me empty/null title and source ! There is no error but still doesn't show anything!

Comment: the only thing that has to be correct was this line
```var items = root.SelectToken("responseHeader").Children().OfType<JProperty>().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value);``` to be replaced by 
```var items = root.SelectToken("").Children().OfType<JProperty>().ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value);```  (empty string) so it will take the whole response and check ```item.key=="response"``` and then went into to find ```docs:[url and title]```

Comment: but now the problem is, instead to having only one result in some cases for example if I search for heart it has more than 10 results and I need them all one by one in my title and source, How is it possible?

Comment: You means that the response in json file is a list and it has many items?And you need to add them in the model?